# Strange map behaviour

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between `map(func)` and `map(function(x) { return func(x); })`?

Consider this example:

```js
const lines = '1\n2\n3';
const result = lines.split('\n').map(parseInt);
console.log(result )
```

This returns `[1, NaN, NaN]` which is not what I expected.
However:

```js
const lines = '1\n2\n3';
const result = lines.split('\n').map(function(x){ return parseInt(x)});
console.log(result)
```

returns the expected: `[1, 2, 3]`. What is the difference between  these two forms and why in the first example the result is not `[1, 2, 3]`?

Answer (score 3):

[`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) has a second parameter (radix).

Basically you perform this

```
value index parseInt comment
----- ----- -------- -----------------------------------------------------
  '1'     0        1 with radix 0, and value 1 parseInt assumes radix = 10
  '2'     1      NaN because of the wrong value for the radix
  '3'     2      NaN because of the wrong value for the radix
```

For converting to a number, you could use `Number`.

```js
var lines = '1\n2\n3'

console.log(lines.split('\n').map(Number));
```

For getting integer values, you could use [`Math.floor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) as well.

```js
var lines = '1\n2\n3'

console.log(lines.split('\n').map(Math.floor));
```

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that `.map` passes to its function 3 parameters:

```
.map(element, index, array)
```

when the `parseInt` function accepts 2 arguments

```
parseInt(string, radix)
```

So, you pass index as a radix. That is why your result is wrong. If parseInt was accepting just one argument it would work.

Answer (score 2):

Because the index from the map will be passed into the map function

```
let lines = '1\n2\n3'
let a = lines.split('\n').map(parseInt);
console.log(a)

// Your code above is expanded as below
a = lines.split('\n').map((x, i) => {
  return parseInt(x, i)
})

console.log(a)

// To fix it, use this
lines.split('\n').map(x => parseInt(x));
```